# How to add an auto number next to formatted cells in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So i wanted to add a number next to the formatted cells in the table like:
[image]

The rows are formatted if the the sales rep column to the C2 cell.

I want to make the list look like this where the column F has an auto number list:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(B5=$C$2,MAX($F$4:F4)+1,"")
```

And copy down.

Comment: Oh thanks it worked but can you please explain it if you don't mind

Comment: It looks to see if the name matches if so it finds the max number above it and add 1 to it.  If it does not match it returns an empty string.

Comment: well i understood the if but the max was confusing me but thx so much

Comment: please conseider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.